# jquery scrolling effect approach(scrollpoints, horizontal scroll "hijack")

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, parallax

Probably not the best title, but what I'm looking for is the best approach to create a site with effect similar to this http://www.mdot.it/ "hijacked" vertical scrolling.

Basically I'd know how to do it were it only scrolling down(i.e. if scroll position is 100, fade something out, set something to fixed etc), what I can't get my head around is how to make it work both directions unless I'd use some crazy conditions and stuff.

Can't find the right word to call this effect either, everything I searched for resulted in paralax plugins..

Any tips/patterns/links that would help me?

Thanks!

// edit what mdot is doing is split the whole page into frames(1px 1 frame) and then assign styles for all 52 elements to each frame, so every scrolled pixel there is 52 styles being set.. there has to be a better way, or?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe [skrollr](https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr) is what you want. It's very lightweight and doesn't get in your way.

Comment: Looks good, still want to know how(or what's the best way) to do it, rather than using a plugin, I'll check how he does it, so far it seems similar to what they are using at mdot(assigning css styles to each frame).. Thanks.

Comment: You don't need to do this for each frame. skrollr interpolates the values between them automagically.

Comment: I just realized it's you who made the skrollr, firstly, great job, secondly, I'd still love to make a simplified version from scratch myself. So would you mind giving me a couple of answers if I wrote you an email? Cheers.. 

Other than that, accepting your answer, it's just the right thing for people that only want the parallax-y site done without knowing how it works :)

Comment: Sure, write me at alexander@prinzhorn.it

Answer (score 0):

I was able to dig up http://johnpolacek.github.com/scrolldeck.js/ on google, one of the examples has animations which work in both directions and it looks relatively well thought through - should be a good start.

Comment: I know that one.. that particular example is using http://johnpolacek.github.com/scrollorama/ which is pretty damn heavy weight and does loads of thing I don't need.. I'll look at how he does the fadein/fadeout on scrollup/scrolldown though..

Answer (score 0):

Check the cool scrollpath by Joel Besada:

https://github.com/JoelBesada/scrollpath

Demo [**here**](http://joelb.me/scrollpath/)

Comment: Already built a site on that http://juniorakademie.cz and it's pretty far from what I need :)

Comment: Ah, ok, a pity my answer couldn't help you, hope you find the answer elsewhere :-)  Btw That site is very nice, good job!